# Why I am getting the following error while running appium version 1.18.1?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, sdk, ios-simulator, appium-ios

Getting this error "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: '13.3' does not exist in the list of simctl SDKs. No Simulator SDK versions are available on your system. Please install some via Xcode preferences."

Comment: Apparently, this complains that no simulator for iOS 13.3 was found on your system. As the error says, you can install them via the Xcode Preferences

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exact error and then I updated appium to latest version and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself: requested platform should be visible in `xcrun simctl list` output.

You either use incorrect developer tools dist or Xcode installation is corrupted. Not an [Appium issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11681), but your environment.

Go to XCode and add a new simulator with iOS 13.3, you might need to update XCode as well in oder to do it.